# Setup Python 3.4 package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have recently switched to Python 3. I am trying to create a simple package in the same spirit as done when working in Python 2.7. However, for some reason the package looks empty.

```
setup(
      name="test_py"
    , version="0.1"
    , description="'test_py' package"
    , author=""
    , author_email=""
    , maintainer=""
    , maintainer_email=""
    , long_description="'test_py' package and extensions\n"
    , packages=['test_py'
               ,'test_py.test_py'
               ,'test_py.func'
              ,'test_py.test']
    , package_dir={'test_py.test_py':'test_py/test_py'}  
    , package_data={'test_py.test_py': c_libs}
    )
```

where `test_py/test_py` contains a C++ extension library.

All relevant directories have __init__.py files with content like

```
from test_py import *
```

All worked fine in Python 2.7, but so far no luck in Python 3.4. Any ideas?

Comment: Are they init.py or __init__.py? AFAIK it should be __init__.py and could be empty

Comment: with underscores "\_\_init\_\_.py"

Comment: Oh it the markdown of SO ;) mmh, no idea...

Comment: We can't really help with this question because it is too vague.  Try to reduce the problem: make a small setup.py with just one directory containing one dummy file and see if it works.  Then make it gradually more complex like your real project, and see at which point it stops to work like you expect.  If you do that, you'll likely find the answer to your problem.